# make - substitute all parameters in test objective

Tags: testing, makefile

I'd like to make a "test case" with make

Whay I expect

```
    greet.out -i
    # ciao
```

```
    greet.out -e
    # hello
```

```
    greet.out -f
    # Bonjour
```

My makefile is like

```
    all: build test
    
    build: main.cpp
        g++ main.cpp -o greet.out
    
    test: greet.out
        par = -i -f -e
        // here I'd like to call my app for every parameter I have
        foreach p in $par
        do
        greet.out $p
        done
```

What I'd prefer to avoid:

```
test: greet.out 
    ./greet.out -i
    ./greet.out -e
    ./greet.out -f
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything in a recipe is a shell script.  This:

```
par = -i -f -e
```

is not a valid shell variable assignment.  Probably you mean:

```
par="-i -f -e"
```

Second, every logical line in a recipe is invoked in a *separate* shell.  If you want things to run in the same shell you have to use backslashes to turn multiple physical lines into one logical line.  And if you want to refer to *shell* variables, not *make* variables, you have to escape the `$` as `$$`:

```
test: greet.out
        par="-i -f -e"; \
        for p in $$par; do \
            greet.out $$p; \
        done
```

Alternatively, you could use an actual make variable for `par`, but then it can't be in the recipe:

```
par = -i -f -e

test: greet.out
        for p in $(par); do \
            greet.out $$p; \
        done
```